# LI that does not contain a link test

Tags: jquery

I can't figure this out. I've done some searching and what I've found, I would think would work, but it doesn't.

I have a structure like this.

And when you click on a number, the anchor is removed. when you subsequently click on another number, I want to know WHICH li's do NOT have a anchor in it, or its text that isn't wrapped by an anchor. Not matter the test, i always get the full range of the li's.. it never passes my test.

In the following case, I am reiterating thru a collection of LI's from an element.

```
var page = jQuery('#thiselement');

       jQuery.each(page.find('li'),function(){
         if(jQuery(':not(:has(a))',this)){
            // also tried jQuery(this), no luck
            // no matter what, it ALWAYS falls in this conditional 
            // if the LI has a link or not, it gets in here
         }
        }



    <ul id="thiselement">
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need wrap whatever passes the test in an anchor tag. So, lets say when the test is conditional is run, we have:

```
<ul id="thiselement">
 <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
```

Then... the 4th li would pass the test, because that is the "this" that does not have an "a" in it.

Comment: `if(jQuery('a', this).length < 1){// there is no anchor element here }` And you exit loops by returning false...so, `if(jQuery('a', this).length <1){ alert('The LI at Index: '+jQuery(this).index()+' has no anchor element!'); return false; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your looking to do is find the list items without anchors, try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var page = $("#thiselement")
        page.find("li:not(:has(a))").wrap('<a href="#">');
    });
</script>
<ul id="thiselement">
 <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, if you need to do something more, try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var page = $("#thiselement")
        page.find("li:not(:has(a))").each(function(){
            $(this).wrap('<a href="#">'); 
        });
    });
</script>
<ul id="thiselement">
 <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Summary:
This will find all list items without anchor tags

$("#thiselement").find("li:not(:has(a))");

OR

$("#thiselement li:not(:has(a))");

Comment: your first example,         page.find("li:not(:has(a))").wrap('<a href="#">');, worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `jQuery(':not(:has(a))',this)` will always be a true value, it might be empty but it will still be true in a boolean context. So tests of the form `if($(x))` aren't terribly useful.

You're also overcomplicating things bit. If you want `<li>`s that don't contain any `<a>`s then you can just do a simple test like this:

```
if($(this).find('a').length == 0)
    // You want this one...
```

If you're expecting to be working with small subtrees and at most one `<a>` at a time then there's no need to overcomplicate things by trying to find an optimal short circuiting selector, just see if what you want is there in a straight forward fashion and move on to more interesting things.

So something like this should make it go:

```
page.find('li').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find('a').length == 0) {
        // Do interesting things here...
    }
});
```

Notice that you don't need `jQuery.each(page.find(...), ...`, you can just call [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on what [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gives you.

You could even rewrite that as a [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) call without much effort.

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wvn6A/

Comment: yeah, I tend to go overboard, I appreciate your response.